# slicing a dataframe based on row and column values within a seperate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The problem is looking up a matrix of values, where the index and row identifier are stored in a separate dataframe, and mapping this value to a new column.

Currently i have the lookup matrix of values pertaining to a wind speed and direction, where the row column names are directional degrees, and the index is the speed value :

value_df:

```
      0     2       4
0     9.7   5.6   4.0
0.1   9.8   5.7   4.1
0.2   7.1   3.6   4.4
0.3   1.1   1.2   0.9
0.4   4.1   3.3   7.5
0.5   4.3   5.8   3.6
0.6   0.6   0.7   9.8
0.7   5.4   0.1   5.4
0.8   7.0   7.4   4.0
0.9   7.9   6.6   8.9
1.0   8.9   7.6   7.4
```

I have a large time series:

met_data_df:

```
DateTime                    Speed     Direction
1999-01-01 00:00:00         0.2     0
1999-01-01 01:00:00         0.3     4
1999-01-01 02:00:00         0.5     2
1999-01-01 03:00:00         1.0     4
1999-01-01 04:00:00         0       4
...                         ...     ...
1999-11-02 11:00:00         0.4     0
1999-11-02 12:00:00         0.9     0
1999-11-02 13:00:00         0.7     0
1999-11-02 14:00:00         0.4     2
1999-11-02 15:00:00         0.3     4
```

What I am looking to do is to map the first matrix to the second, where the value is selected based on the speed vs index and direction value vs row label.

```
DateTime                    Speed   Direction   Value
1999-01-01 00:00:00         0.2     0           7.1
1999-01-01 01:00:00         0.3     4           0.9
1999-01-01 02:00:00         0.5     2           5.8
1999-01-01 03:00:00         1.0     4           7.4
1999-01-01 04:00:00         0       4           ...
...                         ...     ...         ...
1999-11-02 11:00:00         0.4     0
1999-11-02 12:00:00         0.9     0
1999-11-02 13:00:00         0.7     0
1999-11-02 14:00:00         0.4     2
1999-11-02 15:00:00         0.3     4
```

I have tried to build a lambda function, and additional attempt a merge on multiple columns however I have only been able to map the whole row based on wind speed.

```
met_data_df.merge(value_df,left_on='Speed',right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to guarantee your index and column names in `df` are compatible types with speed/direction columns in `df2`... so if Speed/Direction are numeric in `df2` then make sure they're also numeric in `df`... (eg: you might need a `df.columns = pd.to_numeric(df.columns)` etc...)

However, you should be able to use `DataFrame.lookup` here:

```
df2['Value'] = df.lookup(df2['Speed'], df2['Direction'])
```

Comment: Concise answer! I had to recast the direction to str when doing the lookup.  I don't know how I didn't spot this before! Thanks!


`df2['Value'] = df.lookup(df2['Speed'], df2['Direction'].astype(str))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things: [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the `value_df` and then [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) it with `met_data_df`

```py
import pandas as pd

value_df = pd.DataFrame({0: [0, 1, 2, 4],
                         2: [4, 5, 6, 7],
                         4: [8, 9, 10, 11]},
                        index=[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3])

met_data_df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                            'Speed': [0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4],
                            'Direction': [0, 4, 2, 4]})

value_melted = (value_df.reset_index()
                        .melt(id_vars='index'))

value_melted.columns = ['Speed', 'Direction', 'value']
pd.merge(met_data_df, value_melted, on=['Speed', 'Direction'], how='left')
```